# How to make Solr multiple dataimporthandler scheduler in php

Tags: php, solr, dataimporthandler

How to make Solr multiple dataimporthandler scheduler in PHP?

I have multiple dataimport in solrconfig.xml

I want to make a php script which will make index one by one by running url like below...

```
/solr/dataimport1?command=full-import
/solr/dataimport2?command=full-import&clean=false
/solr/dataimport3?command=full-import&clean=false
```

Second url will wait until the first url index not being finish successfully or will through some exception if happens during process. And will not rich to  Maximum execution time say 230.

Please anybody can help me to write the script? or any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly make an http call from php to Solr, if you just want to index the data through DIH.
Note, the above urls are asynchronous, so you would receive an immediate response and need to check the status url to check if the indexing completed successfully or encountered issues.

Also, you can check on Solr Php Clients

There's a [good article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-apachesolr/) here that will help you through the integration of PHP and SOLR:

and [Solr Php Client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/)